# navigator getUserMedia in visualforce page for salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, html5, video

I want to access mediaDevices from a visualforcepage. From within chrome browser the page is working, but when I open it from salesforce1 it somehow gets stuck on the following Promise:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(access){
     j$('#logs').append( '<p>'+access+'</p>' );
  }).catch(function(e){
     j$('#logs').append( '<p>'+e+'</p>' );
  }).finally(function(){
     j$('#logs').append( '<p>finally</p>' );
  });
```

There are no errors in the page, the error is not appended, the finally is not appended, the access object is not appended. It's like a promise that doesn't resolve or reject. Notice that if the same page is opened from the browser all works as expected (you see the access object and the finally printed out)

Any insight? Thanks!

Comment: Did you resolve it ?